# Change screen reader behavior for UWP TextBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, controls

I have written a UserControl that works similar to a PasswordBox but is implemented with a TextBox. The control replaces characters as they are typed with a "dot" character and is used in situations where we don't want to display the actual contents. It is working as desired except that the screen reader will read each character that gets typed, which kind of defeats the purpose. In comparison, when the user types a character in a PasswordBox the Narrator program will say "hidden" instead of the key that was typed.

Is there anything I can do to change the behavior of the screen reader as the user types keys into the TextBox? It would be great if I can have it say "hidden", but it would also be fine to have the screen reader say nothing. I looked at the properties on the AutomationProperties class but didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing a Windows app, the classes that you use for your UI already provide UI Automation support, it enables accessibility applications and assistive technologies, such as screen readers. The Automation for PasswordBox is [PasswordBoxAutomationPeer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.peers.passwordboxautomationpeer?view=winrt-19041), you can check the **Default peer implementation and overrides in PasswordBoxAutomationPeer** part, it overrides the IsPassword method which can prevent screen reader from reading characters.

So you could derive a custom class from TextBox and add automation support for additional features that you enabled in your custom class. Then override OnCreateAutomationPeer so that it returns your custom peer. For example:

```
public class MyCustomAutomationPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
{
    public MyCustomAutomationPeer(MyTextBox owner) : base(owner)
    {
    }

    protected override string GetClassNameCore()
    {
        return "MyTextBox";
    }

    protected override bool IsPasswordCore()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
    {
        return AutomationControlType.Edit;
    }
}


public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        // other initialization; DefaultStyleKey etc.
    }

    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new MyCustomAutomationPeer(this);
    }
}
```

After that, you could replace characters as they are typed with a "dot" character in MyTextBox. In addition, for more details about custom automation peers, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/accessibility/custom-automation-peers).

Comment: Thank you Faywang - that was exactly what I needed.